# JPA Native Query Issue

Tags: jpa, nativequery

I am facing an issue with JPA by trying to execute Native Query with a SQL SERVER 2008 database. I don't really understand what is happening. 
When I execute the query directly in the  database I got the following result (which is what I am expecting):

```
DS  Node    Total   MinDate     MaxDate
EMM CCND    7796    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM CCNV    12049   2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM CGSN    1252    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM MSC     7456    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM SMSC    3999    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
```

but in the code, the result is not the same when I retrieve the data from my EntityManager.
What I get is the following:

```
DS  Node    Total   MinDate     MaxDate
EMM CCND    7796    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM CCND    7796    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM CCND    7796    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM CCND    7796    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
EMM CCND    7796    2013-04-16  2013-04-22
```

I am getting the same result in the same line. Very strange...
Please, can someone help me understand what is the issue. I was suspecting PrimeFaces `subtable` component, not to able display good data, but now I am sure that the issue come from JPA Native Query.
See below the query I am using :

```
"select distinct DownStream.IDDownStream as DownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR as Node, COUNT(CDR.NomSortie) as TotalFiles," + 
" MIN(convert(varchar(19),DateCDR,120)) as MinDate, MAX(convert(varchar(19),DateCDR,120)) as MaxDate" + 
" from DownStream, CDR, Equipement, PortailMediation" + 
" where DownStream.IDDownStream = Equipement.IDDownStream" +
" and PortailMediation.IDEquipement = Equipement.IDEquipement" + 
" and CDR.IDPortailMediation = PortailMediation.IDPortailMediation" +
" and DownStream.Nom = '" + downStream + 
"' and convert(varchar(10),DateCDR,103) between '" +  beginStr + "' and '" + endStr +
"' group by DownStream.IDDownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR" +
" order by DownStream.IDDownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR";
```

See below the code of the query :

```
public class QueryManager {    
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    private String beginStr;
    private String endStr;

    /**
     * 
     * @param beginDate
     * @param endDate
     * @return 
     */
    public String getGroupedQuery(Date beginDate, Date endDate){        
        beginStr = sdf.format(beginDate);
        endStr = sdf.format(endDate);
        String groupedQuery = "select DownStream.IDDownStream as DownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR as Node, COUNT(CDR.NomSortie) as TotalFiles," + 
                              " MIN(convert(varchar(19),DateCDR,120)) as MinDate, MAX(convert(varchar(19),DateCDR,120)) as MaxDate" + 
                              " from DownStream, CDR, Equipement, PortailMediation" + 
                              " where DownStream.IDDownStream = Equipement.IDDownStream" +
                              " and PortailMediation.IDEquipement = Equipement.IDEquipement" + 
                              " and CDR.IDPortailMediation = PortailMediation.IDPortailMediation" + 
                              " and convert(varchar(10),DateCDR,103) between '" +  beginStr + "' and '" + endStr +
                              "' group by DownStream.IDDownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR" +
                              " order by DownStream.IDDownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR"; 

        return groupedQuery;                     
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param beginDate
     * @param endDate
     * @param downStream
     * @return 
     */
    public String getGroupedQueryByDownStream(Date beginDate, Date endDate, String downStream) {
        beginStr = sdf.format(beginDate);
        endStr = sdf.format(endDate);
        String groupedQuery = "SELECT DownStream.IDDownStream AS DownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR AS Node, COUNT(CDR.NomSortie) AS TotalFiles," + 
                              " MIN(convert(varchar(19),DateCDR,120)) AS MinDate, MAX(convert(varchar(19),DateCDR,120)) AS MaxDate" + 
                              " FROM DownStream, CDR, Equipement, PortailMediation" + 
                              " WHERE DownStream.IDDownStream = Equipement.IDDownStream" +
                              " AND PortailMediation.IDEquipement = Equipement.IDEquipement" + 
                              " AND CDR.IDPortailMediation = PortailMediation.IDPortailMediation" +
                              " AND DownStream.Nom = '" + downStream + 
                              "' AND convert(varchar(10),DateCDR,103) BETWEEN '" +  beginStr + "' AND '" + endStr +
                              "' GROUP BY DownStream.IDDownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR" +
                              " ORDER BY DownStream.IDDownStream, PortailMediation.IDNoeudOrigineCDR"; 

        return groupedQuery;      
    }
}
```

The code of the EJB that call the List:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import tg.moov.imereport.dao.DownStreamTotal;
import tg.moov.imereport.util.QueryManager;


@Named
@Stateless
public class DownStreamTotalEJB {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em; 
    private QueryManager qm = new QueryManager();

    public DownStreamTotalEJB() {

    }

    /**
     * Get the grouped files by period
     * @param begin
     * @param end
     * @return 
     */
    public List<DownStreamTotal> getGroupedData(Date begin, Date end) {        
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(qm.getGroupedQuery(begin, end), DownStreamTotal.class);        
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * Get the grouped files by period and by downStream
     * @param begin
     * @param end
     * @param downStream
     * @return 
     */
    public List<DownStreamTotal> getGroupedDataByDownStream(Date begin, Date end, String downStream) {        
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(qm.getGroupedQueryByDownStream(begin, end, downStream), DownStreamTotal.class);
        return q.getResultList();       
    }
}
```

The EJB call the Query Manager to get the query to execute.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: How are you sure JPA is the issue?  Have you printed off or debugged the result of the collection to verify all 5 Object[] returned in the collection are the same as it is returned from the getResultList() call?

Comment: Yes, I have also try to get the values individualy by iterate in to them, and I notices that, I have the same values. But for the same query executed in the database, I have another result.

Comment: show your code then, as the string isn't enough to go on.

Comment: I agree that there isn't much to go on but I did notice that you are not using "distinct" in the QueryManager nor controlling that with jpa in DownStreamTotalEJB. Though the query you display right above those two has "distinct" in it. Might be something there.

Comment: I try with DISTINCT, but the result is the same. Also noticed that my EJB is wrapped in a Web Service. Help !

Comment: The function I am executing is : getGroupedDataByDownStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I have abandon JPA, and I am using JDBC direct connection with Glassfish JNDI, and it works fine.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue using Eclipselink with SQL SERVER 2008.

After creating a query with `createNativeQuery(queryString, targetEntity)`, seems that is working only by using `.getSingleResult()`, but not with `.getResultList()`. It returns N times the first entity.

I am afraid that by the moment the only way out is to retrieve the data as `List<Object[]>` by using `createNativeQuery(queryString)` and do the mapping manually.